# How to fix "404 Page not found" error in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, .htaccess

I had a project in codeigniter setup on localhost. And today I put the same project on server. On localhost it was working fine but after moving it to online server, it is not working and giving only "404 Page not found" error.

To resolve it, I changed the $config['base_url'] and the .htaccess file I'm using is below:

```
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I may not sure but check your controller name and model names... dose they start with capital later ... i mean ... at server it effect ... if you have controller with name ... `xyz_controller.php` .. chage it to `Xyz_controller.php` .. same for models .. do that .. and same with class name ... it need to star with capital later ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21873089)

Comment: then read the same think from documentation .. they mention how to use controller and every think ... i did the same think and solved the problem... at codeigniter documentation go for controllers and read the importance .. it is a frame work which has some case sensitive requirement ..